# Filepond with Django returns empty filelist

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, django-views, filepond

I am trying to use file pond with my Django but after the images are preview and it displays them as green and I see the POST request, after clicking submit n my form when I print request.files it returns an empty list.

This is my Django view:

```
@login_required
def post_create(request):
    data = dict()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = PostForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():  
            post = form.save(False)
            post.author = request.user
            post.save()
            if request.FILES is not None:
                images = request.FILES.getlist('filepond')
                print(images)
                for i in images:
                    image_instance = Images.objects.create(image=i,post=post)
                    image_instance.save()
            data['form_is_valid'] = True
            data['post'] = render_to_string('home/posts/new_post.html',{'post':post},request=request)
        else:
            data['form_is_valid'] = False
    else:
        form = PostForm      
    context = {
    'form':form,
    }
    data['html_form'] = render_to_string('home/posts/post_create.html',context,request=request)
    return JsonResponse(data)
```

Andd this is my html with script:

```
<form method="POST" data-url="{% url 'home:post-create' %}" class="post-create-form" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {% csrf_token %}
        <div class="modal-header text-center">
            <h5 class="modal-title col-12 text-center">Create a Post
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
            </button>
        </h5>
        </div>
    <div class="modal-body" style="height:400px;overflow-y: auto; margin:0;">
        {{ form|crispy }}
        <div class="pt-3" style="margin-bottom: -100px !important;">
            <input type="file" class="filepond" accept="image/*">
        </div>


    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer col-12" style="margin-top: -20px;">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"  style="border-radius: 20px; width: 100%;">Post</button>
    </div>
</form>
<script>
    $.fn.filepond.registerPlugin(
        FilePondPluginImagePreview,
        FilePondPluginImageCrop,
        FilePondPluginImageEdit,
        FilePondPluginImageEdit,
        FilePondPluginFileValidateType,
        );
    $(function () {
        var csrf_token="{{ csrf_token }}";
        $('.filepond').filepond({
            allowMultiple: true,
            className: "d-flex",
            maxFiles: 4,
            allowFileTypeValidation: true,
            acceptedFileType:['image/png', 'image/jpeg'],
            dropOnPage: true,
            server: {
            process: {
                headers: {"X-CSRFToken":csrf_token,},
                url: '/home/post/create/',
                method: 'POST',
            },
            revert: {
                headers: {
                "X-CSRFToken":csrf_token,
                },
                url: '/home/post/create/',
                method: 'DELETE',
            },
            fetch: null,
            load: null,
            },
            labelIdle: '<span class="filepond--label-action">Add Photos</span>',
            imagePreviewHeight: 250,

        });
    })
</script>
```

What is causing this issue as I can see the files being uploaded and I set the server URL to which handles the POST request how am I suppose to fix this? I have already tried renaming input field but nothing is being returned in Django when I print the files.

Answer (score 0):

The files are already uploaded. You won't receive another files list, you'll receive an array of file ids (the id's returned by this endpoint `'/home/post/create/`).

You can then move files from the temp directory, where the process end point should put files, to a more final location.